# For which values of a, b and c is this matrix diagonizable?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Consider the matrix $$\begin{pmatrix}\lambda &a&b\\ 0&\mu &c\\ 0&0&\upsilon \end{pmatrix}$$ $\lambda$ ,$\mu$ and $\upsilon$ are distinct real numbers. How do I find the values of a, b and c for which this matrix is diagonizable or not?

I know that, since it is a triangular matrix, it's eigenvalues are the elements in the diagonal, and that, in order to be diagonizable, it has to have 3 linearly independent eigenvectors. But where do I go from here?

Comment: This matrix is always diagonalisable. Distinct eigenvalues produces linearly independent eigenvectors.

Comment: Right! thank you. But what if insteat of a mu I had another lambda, for exemple -- how would I do it?

Comment: Try to find the eigenspaces corresponding to each eigenvalue. If they have dimensions which add to $3$ then it is diagonalisable.

Comment: That is another question. I suggest that you post it as such.

Comment: I believe if any of $\lambda=0, \mu=0$ or $\upsilon = 0$, then it will not be diagonalizable, regardless of the values of $a,b,c$. Making them distinct real numbers does not make them non-zero.

Comment: "It has 3 linearly independent eigenvectors" is exactly what diagonalizable means